# Delete a row from a table in HTML after adding new record with same attribute

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, html-table

I am using laravel to show a table (from MySQL) in browser. The table has 3 column (IP, time, status). now when a new record added to MySQL, new row is added to the table, I want to first check if the IP of new record is already in the table, time and status of it update with new values, in another word I want to delete the old row (if IPs are the same) and add new one to the table, so I always have the last time and status of each IPs and not duplicate row with same IP in the table. Here is my code:

```
<h1 Style = " margin-top : 100px;" >Last state of each Host</h1>
    <table  class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" >IP</th>
            <th scope="col">date_time</th>
            <th scope="col">status</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if(isset($result))
            @foreach($result as $t)

                <tr class="bg-info">
                    @foreach($ipt as $s)
                        @if($t -> date_time === $s -> date_time)
                            <td>{!! $s -> IP!!}</td>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    <td>{!! $t -> date_time!!}</td>
                    <td>{!! $t -> status!!}</td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach

        @endif

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: How do you refresh the table when a new row is added in the DB? Because you can query the database by the time object in ascending or descending order and group by the IP address.

Comment: Use AJAX to refresh the latest data in the HTML table view

Comment: I wrote Queries in controller, but as you see in my code it is a little complicated (it is not a single table in DB). so I think it would be easier if could handle it in my blade. @nakov

Comment: I could refresh it in my code, my problem is I want to replace status and time of each IP. @ManojSingh

Comment: blade required latest data to reflect in table view, call AJAX with a time interval that check and get latest data from controller method and update blade data without page reload.

Comment: Thank you @ManojSingh , but I don't know AJAX. BTW I'll search about it.

Comment: You can share your table structure and I can help you with a query, it will be much more efficient than doing it in the view. It is good practice to not make any business logic in the view.

Comment: instead of doing that, why not search the row containing that IP and update the fields along with sorting the results based on updated_at column.

Comment: Thank you @nakov , I found an idea, let me try that and if it does not work out, I will ask another question with the information you said.

Comment: yes it is a good idea but I don't know how to do that. I think it needs JS which I don't know. @BonishKoirala

Comment: If you are not familiar with JS then you should update your MySQL query to select the latest time for each IP address.

Answer (score 1):

you can you laravel eloquent query function updateOrCreate, By using this function you don't have to delete any record. see my code this is definitely help you.

```
App\IPs::updateOrCreate([
'IP'   => $ip,
],[
'status' => $status,
'time' => $time,
```

]);

Comment: Thank you @Videsh , but I changed my query in controller and my problem solved.